# encryption - machinekey

Tags: .net, encryption, cryptography, machinekey

I'm trying to figure out a secure way of encrypting a couple of fields in my database using C# for my web app.

I need to find a script that does the encryption/decryption and a way of storing the key. I read that you can use the machinekey as a key, is that correct?

There are autogenerated and non-autogenerated machinekeys. I think I would rather go with the non-autogenerated, as this way it will be easy to deploy my web app into different servers. I found this tool where it generates one for you:

http://aspnetresources.com/tools/machineKey

What encryption/decryption script would work with this machinekey?

Also I was wondering, how secure is it to store the non-autogenerated machine key in the web.config file? If someone can see the web.config file, why use machinekey instead of a "normal" key in appSettings for instance?

Answer (score 0):

According to that article, a 256-bit decryption key and a 512-bit validation key are generated and they go with the Rijndael algorithm, so you need a C# implementation of it which is already in the `System.Security.Cryptography` namespace.

Here is two functions that do the work:

```
private static string EncryptString(string clearText, 
                                    string strKey, string strIv) {

    byte[] plainText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(clearText);

    byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strKey);

    // a simple initialization vector
    byte[] iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strIv);


    RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();

    //Define the Mode
    rijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

    ICryptoTransform aesEncryptor = rijndael.CreateEncryptor(key, iv);

    MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();

    // writing data to MemoryStream
    CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, aesEncryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write);
    cs.Write(plainText, 0, plainText.Length);
    cs.FlushFinalBlock();

    byte[] CipherBytes = ms.ToArray();

    ms.Close();
    cs.Close();

    return Convert.ToBase64String(CipherBytes);
}
```

And :

```
public static string DecryptString(string cipherText, 
                                   string strKey, string strIv) {

          byte[] cipheredData = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);
          byte[] key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strKey);

          byte[] iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strIv);

          RijndaelManaged rijndael = new RijndaelManaged();
          rijndael.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

          ICryptoTransform decryptor = rijndael.CreateDecryptor(key, iv);
          MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(cipheredData);
          CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(ms, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read);

          byte[] plainTextData = new byte[cipheredData.Length];

          int decryptedByteCount = cs.Read(plainTextData, 0, plainTextData.Length);

          ms.Close();
          cs.Close();

          return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(plainTextData, 0, decryptedByteCount);
}
```

And about your second question, the generated machinekey is a hexadecimal string which is human readable but you cannot figure it out.

I hope this help.

Comment: where do these match with the machinekey? string strKey, string strIv

Comment: strKey is your machinekey. strIv which stands for Initialization Vector string is a simple string you can pass whatever value you want.

Comment: can I hardcode strIv  then? also, strKEy should match validationKey or decryptionKey?

Comment: decryptionKey is used to encrypt and decrypt data. This link explain things much better: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff649308.aspx